# Insert parsed JSON into html

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I've tried many methods, from tutorials and other questions posted but nothing seems to work. I'm trying to get data sent from php into divs and variables with jquery. I have the array set up on the php side, and everything works fine but on the jquery side i always get an unexpected identifier error or the div is left blank or both

```
var var_numdatacheck  = <?php echo $datacheck; ?>;
  var var_rowtest = parseInt(var_numdatacheck);
 function waitupdate(){
 $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'update.php',
          data: {function: '3test', datacheck: var_rowtest},
         dataType: "json",
          success: function(check) {
            var data = JSON.parse(check);
                var_rowtest = data[id]; // sets the variable numcheck as the new id number            
                    $('#datacheck').html(data[0]); // I've confirmed data[0] has a value but the div is left blank


            }

  error: function(msg) {
     console.log(msg)// here i get an unexpected identifier error 
  }

        });
    }   


  $(document).ready(function()  {
     waitupdate();
  });
```

The output from the php is

```
{"id":"4","0":"Name"}
```

here is the actual php code

```
<?php
require "dbc.php";

    $function = $_POST['function'];
    $datacheck = $_POST['datacheck'];
    $search="SELECT * FROM Feedtest ORDER BY id DESC";
    $request = mysql_query($search);
    $update= mysql_fetch_array($request);
    $updateid = $update['id'];
    $updatecheck = mysql_num_rows($request);
    $data = array();



    if ($function == $datacheck){
    echo $updatecheck;
    echo $datacheck;
    }

    if ($function == "3test" && $updatecheck > $datacheck )      {    
     $updatesearch="SELECT * FROM Feedtest WHERE id = '$updateid' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $updatequery = mysql_query($updatesearch);
    $check['id'] = $updateid;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($updatequery)){
  ?>

 <?php $check[]= $row['First Name']; ?>
<?php
}

echo json_encode($check); 
} 
?>
</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: it must be `data["0"]` , i think..

Comment: tried that and still a no go : /

Comment: yes its an array encoded in json from the update.php

Comment: can u post ur entire array here then?

Comment: and `function` in `data`.. im pretty sure its not allowed.. try changing it to something else

Comment: change every where data is put in or just function?

Comment: change the name `function` in `data`. also change the same reference on ur server side code as well

Comment: ok did that no change, showing edits in first post.

Comment: what is "datacheck" in  data: {function: '3test', datacheck: var_rowtest} ? is that datacheck or var_numdatacheck?

Comment: datacheck is set to equal 3, this is put into the variable numdatacheck and then the integer parse is what rowtest equals, which should be 3

Comment: `var_rowtest = data[id]; ` <-- where is the variable id defined?

Comment: data is an array from the parsed JSON sent from the update.php so data[id] is equal to check[id].

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you,

```
var var_rowtest = data['id'];
var value= data[0];
```

set variable `var_rowtest` and `value`  in your div as needed.

I guess `var_rowtest = data[id];` is not a proper syntax, use above syntax

Comment: hmm still doesn't seem to work with the ['id'] would it need one for 0?

Comment: hmmm... actually doesn't look like it is now but im sure it was at one point because the http headers showed the post to update.php

Comment: alert the success result, so you will get the idea, is it working or not?

Answer (score 1):

Please try and change your variable names, and that error function declared in the $.ajax threw a JS error for me.

Another thing that is unnecessary is the JSON.parse - I made the PHP script called "update.php" return back the correct header:

```
<?php header('content-type: application/json');?>
```

This code works:

```
var numDataCheck = 1,
    rowTest = parseInt(numDataCheck);
function waitupdate() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'update.php',
        data: {function: '3test', datacheck: rowTest}, dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {               
            rowTest = data.id;
            $('#datacheck').html(data[0]);  
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    waitupdate();
});
```